# How to write HTML text to Microsoft word document using POI or docx4j?

Tags: java, html, docx4j

I am using docx4j to create Microsoft word documents. I also need to write html text to doc. Below is the code I am using, bu when the doc file is generated, its all empty.

```
import org.docx4j.dml.ObjectFactory;
import org.docx4j.jaxb.Context;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.AltChunkType;

public class AltChunkAddOfTypeHtml {

    static String DEST = "/home/Downloads/Sample.docx";

    private static org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
                .createPackage();

        String html =  "<html>पासवर्ड</html>";

        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addAltChunk(AltChunkType.Html,
                html.getBytes());

        wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File(DEST));
    }

}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Below is the code which works properly. Only issue now is setting the font properly. When i set the font in the HTML as below

```
<table border="1px" width="70%" style="font-size: 9px;">
```

Given font size is applied to English text only. It is not applied to the Marathi text.

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.docx4j.XmlUtils;
import org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;

public class ConvertInXHTMLFragment {

    static String SRC = "/home/Downloads/Input.html";
    static String DEST = "/home/Downloads/Sample.docx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String stringFromFile =  "<html>पासवर्ड</html>";
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();

        XHTMLImporterImpl XHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);

        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(XHTMLImporter.convert(stringFromFile, null));

        System.out.println(XmlUtils.marshaltoString(wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getJaxbElement(), true, true));

        wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File(DEST));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

AltChunk relies on the consuming application for support (ie the consuming application converts the HTML payload).

Your output docx works in Microsoft Word (tested 2010).

If you want XHTML converted to real docx content before you save it, so you can see your content in a broader range of consuming applications, see https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/tree/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples

**UPDATE - FONTS**

Fonts are handled by https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/in/xhtml/FontHandler.java#L58

Marathi might be relying on one of the other attributes in the RFonts object.  You'll need to look at a working docx to see.  You can use https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/in/xhtml/FontHandler.java#L54 to inject a suitable font mapping.

Comment: Which one of the above samples addresses the issue?? I could not figure out.

Comment: It Worked. But my HTML text has few Marathi text and English text. Both have font size 9px.  When docx is generated font size is applied to English text but not to Marathi text. Any ideas?

Comment: also the other issue i have is when i try to convert the docs to pdf the marathi texts is displayed as boxes.

Comment: I've updated my answer wrt Marathi.  Please study the linked source code carefully, and if you still have issues, post a new question.  For your PDF issue, you'll need to post a new question,  including how you are converting to PDF.

Comment: Ooops, on re-reading, my answer might not be relevant, since its about fonts, not font size.  You'll need to post sample problematic Marathi input.

Comment: I have added a separate question for pdf issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44262279/how-to-write-html-text-to-pdf-document-using-docx4j

Comment: I have also update the question with sample Marathi text for the font issue.